# Bash/shell script: create four random-length strings with fixed total length

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to create four strings, each with a random length, but their total length should be 10. So possible length combinations could be:

```
3    3    3    1
```

or

```
4    0    2    2
```

Which would then (respectively) result in strings like this:

```
111    222    333    4
```

or

```
1111    33    44
```

How could I do this?

Comment: `4+0+2+2=8`, or am I missing something?

Comment: This seems possible. Edit  your question to tell us : Does randomness cross lines? (are  you trying to write a suduko generator?) Most importantly, edit your question to show what have you tried ;-) Good luck

Comment: @Zloj Nope, I want the lenghts to be generated randomly. I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough, I've added an example.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your response. I've added an example, maybe this makes things clearer. I've managed to create random-length strings with the method described here (https://gist.github.com/earthgecko/3089509), but not to create four random-length strings that together have a length of precisely 16.

Comment: you're heading quickly to an close vote for 'unclear what you're asking'. length of 10, or 16? Also, don't expect people to go to a remote site and have to search around and decide what is relevant. If there is a key point on that site, copy into your question and include a link for the curious. Please ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$RANDOM` will give you a random integer in range `0..32767`.
Using some arithmetic expansion you can do:

```
remaining=10

for i in {1..3}; do
    next=$((RANDOM % remaining)) # get a number in range 0..$remaining
    echo -n "$next "                 
    ((remaining -= next))
done
echo $remaining
```

Update: to repeat the number N times, you can use a function like this:

```
repeat() {
    for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)); do
        echo -n $1
    done
    echo                                         
}

repeat 3
333
```

Comment: All three answers were great, so I've upvoted all three. However, I chose this answer as the preferred one, since it's the most extensive one. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algorithm:

Make first 3 strings with random length, which is not greater than sum of lenght (each time substract it). And rest of length - it's your last string.

Consider this:

```
sumlen=10
for i in {1..3}
do
   strlen=$(($RANDOM % $sumlen)); sumlen=$(($sumlen-$strlen)); echo $strlen
done
echo $sumlen
```

This will output your lengths, now you can create strings, suppose you know how

Answer (score 2):

alternative `awk` solution

```
 awk 'function r(n) {return int(n*rand())} 
      BEGIN{srand(); s=10; 
            for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {a=r(s); s-=a; print a} 
            print s}'

3
5
1
1
```

`srand()` to set a randomized seed, otherwise will generate the same random numbers each time.

Here you can combine the next task of generating the strings into the same awk script

```
$ awk 'function r(n) {return int(n*rand())}; 
       function rep(n,t) {c="";for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c=c t; return c}
       BEGIN{srand(); s=10; 
             for(j=1;j<=3;j++) {a=r(s); s-=a; printf("%s ", rep(a,j))}
             printf("%s\n", rep(s,j))}'
```

generated

```
1111 2 3 4444
```